# Use enzyme to test table which fetches data though post request

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have a `react bootstrap table` which fetches real-time data like following. I would like to add a unit test using enzyme. However, the table needs to fetch real-time data from my url first.

I don't want to fetch data since I didn't insert test data in my database. Is there a way to use fake data to do the test instead of sending post request.

```
class MyTable extends Component {
  getAttachments(){
    const url = `${myUrl}`;
    const data = {id: this.props.id};
    agent.post(url)
      .type('json')
      .set(getAuthHeader())
      .send(data)
      .then( (result) => {
      this.setState({data: result.body});
      console.log(result.body);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.getAttachments();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BootstrapTable data={this.state.data} version='4'>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" dataSort={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name" dataSort={true}>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price" dataFormat={priceFormatter}>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sinon` could be use to mock the request and for such unit test:

```
const promiseEmpty = Promise.resolve([]);

it('should render without exploding', () => {
    const putRequest = sinon.stub(agent.Request.prototype, 'send', () => promiseEmpty);
    const wrapper = shallow(<AttachmentTable {...minProps}/>);
    putRequest.restore();
    return promiseEmpty.then(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.length).to.equal(1);
    });
  });
```